# TypeError: xx2.removeClass is not a function Tiny gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

```
<script language="javascript">
var xx2 = document.getElementById("fotogalerie2");
var button2 = document.getElementById("b2");


button2.addEventListener("click", function () {xx2.removeClass('invisible1').addClass('visible1');} , false);


</script>
<script language="javascript">
var xx22 = document.getElementById("fotogalerie2");
var button222 = document.getElementById("close2");


button222.addEventListener("click", function () {xx22.removeClass('visible1').addClass('invisible1');} , false);


</script>
```

Hi i am using this code for changing class of one div to hide/show him. It working fine. But when i try use tiny gallery(shiba gallery wordpress with tiny gallery look) It stop working and I am getting following error tiny gallery TypeError: xx2.removeClass is not a function
here are my pages http://www.krausbuilding.cz/
bug is in section vybrané reference(reference in menu). There is one visible div just for testing) Anybody knows how fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't open your live site, but starting from the code `xx22` is not a jQuery object so `removeClass` will raise an error because the selector is undefined.

You can create jQuery objects from DOM elements using:

```
$(xx22).removeClass('visible1').addClass('invisible1');
```

Since you are using jQuery for a better code manteinance consider to switch your code to full jQuery usage (event bindings first)